# ESP32 HTTPS OTA. Why embed server certificates?

Tags: https, arduino-esp32, ota

I've been trying out HTTPS OTA updates using the sample program.
https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Update/examples/HTTPS_OTA_Update/HTTPS_OTA_Update.ino

It works as expected but I was wondering why all the examples embed the server certificate in source code like this instead of downloading like the browsers do.

`static const char *server_certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \ "MIIEkjCCA3qgAwIBAgIQCgFBQgAAAVOFc2oLheynCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/\n" \ "MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT\n" \ "DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTE2MDMxNzE2NDA0NloXDTIxMDMxNzE2NDA0Nlow\n" \ "SjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUxldCdzIEVuY3J5cHQxIzAhBgNVBAMT\n" \ "GkxldCdzIEVuY3J5cHQgQXV0aG9yaXR5IFgzMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC\n" \ "AQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnNMM8FrlLke3cl03g7NoYzDq1zUmGSXhvb418XCSL7e4S0EF\n" \ "q6meNQhY7LEqxGiHC6PjdeTm86dicbp5gWAf15Gan/PQeGdxyGkOlZHP/uaZ6WA8\n" \ "SMx+yk13EiSdRxta67nsHjcAHJyse6cF6s5K671B5TaYucv9bTyWaN8jKkKQDIZ0\n" \ "Z8h/pZq4UmEUEz9l6YKHy9v6Dlb2honzhT+Xhq+w3Brvaw2VFn3EK6BlspkENnWA\n" \ "a6xK8xuQSXgvopZPKiAlKQTGdMDQMc2PMTiVFrqoM7hD8bEfwzB/onkxEz0tNvjj\n" \ "/PIzark5McWvxI0NHWQWM6r6hCm21AvA2H3DkwIDAQABo4IBfTCCAXkwEgYDVR0T\n" \ "AQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwfwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEczBxMDIG\n" \ "CCsGAQUFBzABhiZodHRwOi8vaXNyZy50cnVzdGlkLm9jc3AuaWRlbnRydXN0LmNv\n" \ "bTA7BggrBgEFBQcwAoYvaHR0cDovL2FwcHMuaWRlbnRydXN0LmNvbS9yb290cy9k\n" \ "c3Ryb290Y2F4My5wN2MwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUxKexpHsscfrb4UuQdf/EFWCFiRAw\n" \ "VAYDVR0gBE0wSzAIBgZngQwBAgEwPwYLKwYBBAGC3xMBAQEwMDAuBggrBgEFBQcC\n" \ "ARYiaHR0cDovL2Nwcy5yb290LXgxLmxldHNlbmNyeXB0Lm9yZzA8BgNVHR8ENTAz\n" \ "MDGgL6AthitodHRwOi8vY3JsLmlkZW50cnVzdC5jb20vRFNUUk9PVENBWDNDUkwu\n" \ "Y3JsMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSoSmpjBH3duubRObemRWXv86jsoTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF\n" \ "AAOCAQEA3TPXEfNjWDjdGBX7CVW+dla5cEilaUcne8IkCJLxWh9KEik3JHRRHGJo\n" \ "uM2VcGfl96S8TihRzZvoroed6ti6WqEBmtzw3Wodatg+VyOeph4EYpr/1wXKtx8/\n" \ "wApIvJSwtmVi4MFU5aMqrSDE6ea73Mj2tcMyo5jMd6jmeWUHK8so/joWUoHOUgwu\n" \ "X4Po1QYz+3dszkDqMp4fklxBwXRsW10KXzPMTZ+sOPAveyxindmjkW8lGy+QsRlG\n" \ "PfZ+G6Z6h7mjem0Y+iWlkYcV4PIWL1iwBi8saCbGS5jN2p8M+X+Q7UNKEkROb3N6\n" \ "KOqkqm57TH2H3eDJAkSnh6/DNFu0Qg==\n" \ "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";`

Downloading would seem to solve the problem of certificates that become invalid and bricking your OTA. Unless there is some security issue I'm not getting. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a server certificate despite the variable name, it's an expired intermediate CA certificate. As to why, I don't know. Perhaps the TLS/SSL package on this platform doesn't have a collection of trusted CA certificates, so you need to supply your own.

Comment: The browser does not download per se., your PC has about 100+ root certs installed (Microsoft has even more) in your PC. It "update" regularly. If you are using macOS, take a look at `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` file; if you are on ubuntu, `/etc/ssl/certs/ `directory kept all the ca certs. So it make no difference on Arduino, it is need to store somewhere. The only difference is that Arduino (and almost all MCUs) does not kept all the 100+ root ca certs as it doesn't need like a browser do.